# poetryのパスが通らない

Tags: zsh, poetry

## 概要

poetryをubuntuに導入したんですけど、全ッ然パスが通りません。

## やったこと

[image: コマンド履歴]

1. curlでインストール。
2. `.zshrc`の末尾に`export PATH="$HOME/.local/share/pypoetry/venv/bin/poetry:$PATH"`を追加
3. `source`をたたく
4. `poetry -v` → `zsh: command not found: poetry` ←!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$HOME/.local/share/pypoetry/venv/bin/poetry` がコマンドのパスであるなら、PATH に設定するのは「コマンドの存在するディレクトリ」なので以下のようになるはずです。

```
export PATH="$HOME/.local/share/pypoetry/venv/bin:$PATH"
```